# using makefile targets to set build options

Tags: makefile

This is either trivial or runs counter to the philosophy of how make should be used, but I'd like to have a command line that reads as "make debug" rather than "make DEBUG=1". I tried creating a phony target called debug that did nothing except set the DEBUG variable, but then there was a difference between "make debug build" and "make build debug"--namely that in one case, the variable got set after the build happened.

Is there a way to give certain targets precedence?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it by looking at the MAKECMDGOALS variable

```
ifneq "$(findstring debug, $(MAKECMDGOALS))" ""
DEBUG = 1
endif

build:
    @echo build and DEBUG is [$(DEBUG)]

debug:
```

This is what happens when you call it:

```
$ make build
build and DEBUG is []
$ make build debug
build and DEBUG is [1]
make: Nothing to be done for `debug'.
$ make debug build
make: Nothing to be done for `debug'.
build and DEBUG is [1]
```

Answer (score 5):

See 'Target-specific variable values' in [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting).

Comment: No harm mentioning you just have to do `target: DEBUG=1` for a target versus pointing him to the documentation... right?

Comment: Doesn't this not solve the problem that "make build debug" is not equivalent to "make debug build"? This particular feature is exactly what I tried.

Comment: In retrospect, I can see how that matches your question, but you didn't make it clear. Make targets are *always* ordered, so I think you're on an impossible mission.

Comment: In that case, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can write the following:

```
.PHONY: debug
debug:
        $(MAKE) -$(MAKEFLAGS) build DEBUG=1

build:
        echo makeflags='$(MAKEFLAGS)' debug=${DEBUG}
```

This will at least work with GNU Make, BSD Make and Interix Make. I didn't try all the other implementations.

Comment: Portability at the cost of recursive evaluation of the make file.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do with GnuMake is use macros that expand to rules with the `foreach` builtin.  Something like:

```
TARGETS := build all foo bar baz

define DEBUG_TARGET_RULE
$(1).debug:
        $$(MAKE) DEBUG=1 $(1)
debug.$(1):
        $$(MAKE) DEBUG=1 $(1)
endef

$(foreach target,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(call DEBUG_TARGET_RULE,$(target))))
```

This will allow you to type `make debug.foo` or `make foo.debug` and it will automatically turn into `make DEBUG=1 foo`, and it works for any target you put in `$(TARGETS)`

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but cool workaround that also demonstrates a useful feature of make.

Answer (score 0):

If your debug will only be used with the build target, you might as well make debug call build so you can just type `make debug` or `make build`, where `make build` would be non-debug.

But as for your actual question, I'm not familiar enough with makefiles to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to set up the dependencies and build rules in both the build and debug targets, but add the your debugging options to the debug target.  A simple example:

Makefile

```
program:        program.c
                gcc -o program program.c
debug:          program.c
                gcc -D DEBUG -o program program.c
```

Program.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("DEBUG on!\n");
#endif
  printf("in the program\n");
  return 0;
}
```