# how to add a phony target halfway through a make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am looking at a pre-existing, working, complex makefile for a project which will both build and deploy the code on multiple OS's.

I'm looking at some separate IDE support (Visual Studio) for the build process (i.e. half the make will already be done), so need to insert a phony target for the deploy action such that the old flow (`make all`) still works, including the deloy step, but that `make deploy` will just do the final deployment step for those using the IDE.

Not being familiar with make, I'm having difficulty seeing how/if `make` allows such an entry point and if so how to implement it.

The current code has:

```
$(BUILT_INS): git$X
    $(QUIET_BUILT_IN)$(RM) $@ && \
    ln $< $@ 2>/dev/null || \
    ln -s $< $@ 2>/dev/null || \
    cp $< $@
```

whose actions are the deployment step.

So conceptually I think I need

```
.PHONY: deploy
$(BUILT_INS): git$X
  deploy

deploy:
    $(QUIET_BUILT_IN)$(RM) $@ && \
    ln $< $@ 2>/dev/null || \
    ln -s $< $@ 2>/dev/null || \
    cp $< $@
```

which is clearly not right, because the phony target can't be an action.

In summary; How to create an entry point into a makefile to do the rule's actions? (a critical desire is to avoid duplicating the action code)

Answer (score 2):

Your "conceptually" solution has many more problems than using a target as a recipe (which you're right, won't work, but you could fix by using `$(MAKE) deploy` as the recipe to invoke a recursive make); the other thing is that this:

```
$(BUILT_INS):
        ... using $@ ...
```

means run that recipe one time for each word in the `BUILT_INS` variable, and each time the automatic variable `$@` will be assigned to that word (the target).

Your replacement:

```
deploy:
        ... using $@ ...
```

does an entirely different thing: it runs the recipe *one time*, with the value of `$@` set to `deploy`.  Not going to work.

The simple answer to your question is that you just declare a new target `deploy` that lists the targets you want to run as prerequisites:

```
.PHONY: deploy
deploy: $(BUILT_INS)
```

Now when you run `make deploy` it will try to build the `BUILT_INS` targets, and run the install rule for each one.

However, my suspicion is that this will be a problem for you, depending on what the `git$X` prerequisite is... it might cause a big part of the rest of your makefile to run as well.  But, you don't give any information about that so I can't say.

*ETA* Sure enough, `git$X` is a problem.  So, it appears you want VS to generate your `git$X` file (which will be `git.exe` presumably).  Then you want to run `make deploy` to copy it.  The trick here is to keep make from rebuilding `git$X` when you use the `deploy` target.  You can do something like this; replace the rule that builds `git$X` with:

```
.PHONY: deploy
deploy: $(BUILT_INS)

ifeq (,$(filter deploy,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
git$X: git.o GIT-LDFLAGS $(BUILTIN_OBJS) $(GITLIBS)
        $(QUIET_LINK)$(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -o $@ $(ALL_LDFLAGS) git.o \
            $(BUILTIN_OBJS) $(LIBS)
endif
```

This creates a new target `deploy` which depends on the `BUILT_INS` targets, as I show above.  Then, I enclose the rule to create `git$X` inside a test so that if you run `make deploy` that rule is not defined.  Now make doesn't know how to build `git$X` at all, so if it doesn't exist then `make deploy` will fail, but if it does exist then make will copy it, without trying to rebuild it.

Comment: I'd had a look at something like that, but realised that the thing I didn't want to happen was for the `BUILT_INS` to be built (as dependancies) by the make file - I simply want the the list of names to feed into the deploy action - all very awkward to achieve.

Comment: Well, presumably they already exist when you run `make deploy`, otherwise it cannot work.  If they exist, then make won't try to rebuild them -- _unless their prerequisites are out-of-date_!  This is exactly what I was referring to by my comment above about `git$X` (whatever that is).  Without knowing what the prerequisites of the `BUILT_INS` targets are we can't provide a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the `BUILT_INS` may be out of date or missing (rather than `git$X` which will be newly built), because of the independence of the tools, hence the desire to find a way of inserting an entry point. The full makefile is here https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L1678 - this is the final step after the git executable is built when it is linked or copied to the built-ins, so having built that executable with VS one just wants to do that deployment, but as you see 'it's complicated'.

Comment: I don't understand how you can call a `deploy` rule which you want to just install the `BUILT_INS`, if some of them are missing.  My understanding of what you're trying to do is build the `BUILT_INS` targets using Visual Studio, not make, but then install them with make by running a separate target that does the install bit.  That's why I said above _they already exist when you run `make deploy`_ ... because VS must have already created them.

Comment: The odd thing which you may have noticed is that the `BUILT_INS` aren't actually 'built', rather they are linked or copied *by that rule* from the `git$X` dependency, so given a new 'git$X` (externally built by VS) I need to then run that script to 'duplicate' that 'git$X` into the `BUILT_INS`, preferably using the same piece of script to avoid future maintenance hassles of keeping separate script parts synchronised.

Comment: Also the `git$X` depends on a previous rule that depends on a separate macro variable `BUILTIN_OBJS`, so it can end up a bit circular (see #L601 as linked above).

Comment: The *ETA* section regarding the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable looks a good method. The one other thought I had (after more browsing) was the inverse of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784557/717355 and add a `DEPLOY_ONLY=1` on the command line (instead of the debug target) and then append that to the appropriate `git$X` target to break the invocation of the rule you'd identified. I'll try them !